# Via Woocommerce/ Wordpress admin, target the order name label and child name field

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce, css-selectors

I have a client that uses woo commerce with Wordpress. When viewing an order, they wish for any order using the 'naming field'  to be highlighted, which would include the childs name with a background colour.

When I try and do this, I only seem to be able to target multiple fields within the page, highlighting them all.

Can some one assit to help me target just these fields, even if its using a PHP edit?

[image]

[image]

Comment: There are not many CSS classes or PHP filters to change the classes there to use. You may need to us Javascript.

Comment: is `name label` is coming from any custom fields ?

Comment: @ Raunak Gupta I just added a new image that shows the front end options to the buyer and where name is entered. here is a link https://plschoolwear.co.uk/shop/haddenham-st-marys/pe-shorts-royal-blue/

Comment: Add the `DOM` to which you wanna target using `CSS` that would be much helpful rather than the images.