# Target certain field box name using CSS /Woo Commerce/Wordpress

Tags: php, css, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm trying to understand how I can use CSS to target the text below that says 'Nathan' this is a custom field within WooCOmmerce /Wordpress, but if its possible to target the name field only that will mean I can change the background colour. My thinking is that the CSS principles for targeting this box are the same, no matter that its a WordPress backend.

Any help would be gratefully received.

[image]

Comment: can you share the code that you have used to generate the custom fields?  because I think there bust be an option to pass custom class. and is it related to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43592501/via-woocommerce-wordpress-admin-target-the-order-name-label-and-child-name-fie)

Answer (score 0):

You can target exactly this field with the `>` selector. Concrete example:

```
.display_meta > tbody > tr > td > p {
    color: red;
}
```

If the class `.display_meta` is used only once this would be fine, else as commented on your question there may be a better way to do this; a custom class would be better, because it makes you css easier readable, and does not produce any strange side effects (as the code provided might will)